# Ember 2 best practices

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to find best practices for ember 2 related to class defining. I have a few questions...

- Are we supposed to be using the ECMA6 "class", or does ember strictly rely on Ember.Object.extend?
- If my class is not supposed to be an ember service does that auto make it a Utility?
- Do all custom classes belong in Utility, or is it okay to create
  another folder for my classes?

More specifically my class is a wrapper for server sent events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are we supposed to be using the ECMA6 "class", or does ember strictly
>   rely on Ember.Object.extend?

I find Ember.js to be a strict framework. But it does not strictly rely on `Ember.Object.extend`. You can use whatever you want that is valid Javascript.
However, in my experience I would not try to re-implement too much stuff myself. Also, please note not inheriting from Ember.Object will prevent you from using these methods : http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html.

> Do all custom classes belong in Utility, or is it okay to create
>   another folder for my classes

Why would you create a new folder ? Ember-cli already provides you with Services and Utilities.

Comment: I think you may be wrong with the difference of Services and Utilities. They have a Utility class in the examples: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/tutorial/service/ . So I don't think the difference is the grouping of methods/functions. It looks like services are more of just singletons that last forever, and carry a state. Your answer helped with trying to figure out how strict I need to follow ECMA6.

Comment: Thanks for your link. I have updated my answer to remove my assertion on Service vs Utility in order not to add confusion to this thread.